# How to change default message of a merging commit on Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Is there any way to change the default commit message for pull requests merged via Bitbucket? When I click "Merge" button on top of a pull request page, the resulting commit has a default message like

> Merged in some-branch (pull request #25)

The problem is the fragment `#25` because I often push the same repository also to GitHub which links the number to the issue no. 25. I know that there is a text area where I can edit the message before each merge but it's really hard to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't currently possible to do with BitBucket. I'll update this answer if that ever changes, however.

You could potentially do a *hazardous* `git rebase -i` or `git commit --amend` and force push after the fact to rectify the issue if you **know for certain no one else has pulled** and is working off of the commit you are about to change...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the hazardous `git rebase -i` as proposed by @Stunner, you can just do a local merge with customized message.

```
git fetch origin refs/pull-requests/123/from
git merge FETCH_HEAD
(git push origin)
```

Options you can use with git-merge are `-e`, `-m` and `--no-ff`, depending on your desired style.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the same to implement some automation.

I found it
https://jira.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/BSERV-8384

If more people vote on this ticket we may have this option in some release